# There is an error in my stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a problem with my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TIGER_CREATE_RUNTIME_TABLE](@NOMBRE_TABLA varchar(100))
AS
    DECLARE @SQLQUERY1 AS NVARCHAR(600)
BEGIN
    SET @SQLQUERY1 = 'CREATE TABLE '+@NOMBRE_TABLA + '(
    SEGMENTO varchar(200) NULL,
    TCNFOL varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    TCCOPL_A varchar(200) NULL,
    ID_LIN_NEG varchar(200) NULL,
    TIP_LIN varchar(200) NULL,
    MON_ID_MONEDA varchar(200) NULL,
    LINEAS_FACT varchar(200) NULL,
    CF_VOZ varchar(200) NULL,
    CF_DATOS varchar(200) NULL,
    ADIC_MINS varchar(200) NULL,
    ADIC_LDN varchar(200) NULL,
    ADIC_LDI varchar(200) NULL,
    ADIC_SMS varchar(200) NULL,
    PAQ_SMS varchar(200) NULL,
    ADIC_DATOS varchar(200) NULL,
    OTROS varchar(200) NULL,
    SUB_TOT varchar(200) NULL,
    PERIODO_ANALISIS varchar(200) NULL,
    PERIODO_ALTA varchar(200) NULL,
    CATEGORIA varchar(200) NULL,
    RUC varchar(200) NULL)'

    EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @SQLQUERY1
END
```

As you can see, I'm using dynamic SQL, but there is an error while I execute it.

> *Mens. 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>
>   Incorrect syntax near 'varch'.*

Is there any wrong with dynamic SQL? Thanks for a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would change your `@sqlquery1` to `varchar(max)`, I think you are hitting the character limit when you add your table name:

```
 DECLARE @SQLQUERY1 AS NVARCHAR(max)
```

You have your limit of your query string set to 600 but when you add in a table name of up to `varchar(100)` you are most likely going over the limit.

If you run just the following with no table name the len is 726 characters:

```
DECLARE @SQLQUERY1 AS NVARCHAR(max)

SET @SQLQUERY1 = 'CREATE TABLE (
    SEGMENTO varchar(200) NULL,
    TCNFOL varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    TCCOPL_A varchar(200) NULL,
    ID_LIN_NEG varchar(200) NULL,
    TIP_LIN varchar(200) NULL,
    MON_ID_MONEDA varchar(200) NULL,
    LINEAS_FACT varchar(200) NULL,
    CF_VOZ varchar(200) NULL,
    CF_DATOS varchar(200) NULL,
    ADIC_MINS varchar(200) NULL,
    ADIC_LDN varchar(200) NULL,
    ADIC_LDI varchar(200) NULL,
    ADIC_SMS varchar(200) NULL,
    PAQ_SMS varchar(200) NULL,
    ADIC_DATOS varchar(200) NULL,
    OTROS varchar(200) NULL,
    SUB_TOT varchar(200) NULL,
    PERIODO_ANALISIS varchar(200) NULL,
    PERIODO_ALTA varchar(200) NULL,
    CATEGORIA varchar(200) NULL,
    RUC varchar(200) NULL)'

select LEN(@sqlquery1)
```

If you leave your query string at a length of `600` your create table statement will be cut off and will generate an error.

Comment: The create statement is good (if pulled out and run on its own) so that is the next logical spot.